# How to make monetary field greater than & less than value in AWK?

Tags: awk

I have the following:

```
field:field:field:$90.00:field
field:field:field:$85.00:field
```

I'm trying to make field $4 greater than or = to 90, and less than 100, however, I got my awk statement wrong somewhere and I cant figure out where and why its wrong.

```
awk -F: '{gsub("\$","",$4); if ($4 >= 90 && $4 < 100) print $1 ":" $2 " " $4 }' file.txt > output.txt
```

I tried to remove the $ sign to make it more like an integer, How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sub`, as you're only looking to perform a single substitution, not a global one. Also, use a regular expression literal, rather than a string, which is first parsed by awk and as such, requires double-escaping:

```
sub(/\$/, "", $4)
```

Optionally you could add an anchor to the start of the field `/^\$/`.

Personally, I think it's nicer to use commas in your `print` command to insert the Output Field Separator (a space by default).

Also, remember that the structure of an awk program is `condition { action }` so often, you don't need to write an `if`.

Combining all that:

```
awk -F: '{ sub(/\$/, "", $4) } ($4+0) >= 90 && ($4+0) < 100 { print $1":"$2, $4 }' file.txt > output.txt
```

Arguably you could make the `sub` part of the condition as it will return `1` (true) when it makes a substitution but I don't think there's much of an advantage to doing so.

Note that I have added `0` to the field to make sure that a numerical comparison is performed. The reason for this is given in the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Typing.html#Variable-Typing):

> A string constant or the result of a string operation has the string attribute.

Comment: thanks :), i got some weird stuff happening, if i edit the awk values and make it 80 to 90 i get nothing, I have to change $$ to || and back again for it to work, and same thing if i wanna change awk back to 90 to 100.. does awk cache anything?

Comment: Thanks the answer is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "$x" | awk -F: '{gsub("\\$","",$4); if ($4 >= 90 && $4 < 100) print $1 ":" $2 " " $4 }'
field:field 90.00
```

double escape  dollar sign.